# using multiple select to join data from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE years (
year_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
year_name_in_nums int NOT NULL,
year_name_in_text varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (year_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE classes (
class_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
class_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (class_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE students (
student_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
student_names varchar(255) NOT NULL,
student_telephone_number int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE terms (
term_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
term_name_in_nums int NOT NULL,
term_name_in_text varchar(255) NOT NULL,
term_year int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (term_id),
FOREIGN KEY (term_year) REFERENCES years(year_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE class_students (
cs_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
cs_class_student int NOT NULL,
cs_class_id int NOT NULL,
cs_term_id int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (cs_id),
FOREIGN KEY (cs_class_student) REFERENCES students(student_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (cs_class_id) REFERENCES classes(class_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (cs_term_id) REFERENCES terms(term_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to display `term_name_in_nums` from the terms table and `year_name_in_nums` from the years table

I retrieved the data this way

```
(select term_name_in_nums,term_year from terms INNER JOIN class_students ON term_id=cs_term_id);
```

From the above,`term_year` is a FOREIGN KEY (term_year) which REFERENCES years(year_id)

I am trying this

```
(select term_name_in_nums from terms INNER JOIN class_students ON term_id=cs_term_id)
  LEFT JOIN
 (select term_year from terms INNER JOIN class_students ON term_id=cs_term_id);
```

This gives me an sql syntax error.How can i fix this?.

Edit:The Data

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         127.0.0.1
-- Server version:               5.6.11 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
-- Server OS:                    Win32
-- HeidiSQL Version:             8.0.0.4396
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
-- Dumping data for table algo.classes: ~10 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `classes` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `classes` (`class_id`, `class_name`) VALUES
    (1, '1'),
    (2, '2'),
    (3, '3'),
    (4, '4'),
    (5, '5'),
    (6, '6'),
    (7, '7'),
    (8, '8'),
    (9, '9'),
    (10, '10');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `classes` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Dumping data for table algo.class_students: ~16 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `class_students` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `class_students` (`cs_id`, `cs_class_student`, `cs_class_id`, `cs_term_id`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 1, 1),
    (3, 2, 1, 1),
    (4, 3, 1, 1),
    (5, 4, 1, 1),
    (6, 5, 1, 1),
    (7, 6, 1, 1),
    (8, 7, 1, 1),
    (9, 8, 1, 1),
    (10, 9, 1, 1),
    (11, 10, 1, 1),
    (12, 11, 1, 1),
    (13, 12, 1, 1),
    (14, 13, 1, 1),
    (15, 14, 1, 1),
    (16, 15, 1, 1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `class_students` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Dumping data for table algo.examinations: ~3 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `examinations` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `examinations` (`examination_id`, `examination_name`, `examination_term_id`) VALUES
    (1, 'start of term', 1),
    (2, 'mid term', 1),
    (3, 'end of term', 1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `examinations` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Dumping data for table algo.examination_data: ~0 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `examination_data` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `examination_data` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Dumping data for table algo.students: ~20 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `students` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `students` (`student_id`, `student_names`, `student_telephone_number`) VALUES
    (1, 'aa', 123456),
    (2, 'bb', 5576899),
    (3, '23050359165419520', 788399),
    (4, '23050359165419521', 7892020),
    (5, '23050359165419522', 33772),
    (6, '23050359165419523', 86729),
    (7, '23050359165419524', 526890),
    (8, '23050359165419525', 444332),
    (9, '23050359165419526', 937678),
    (10, '23050359165419527', 44),
    (11, '23050359165419528', 774),
    (12, '23050359165419529', 2147483647),
    (13, '23050359165419531', 2147483647),
    (14, '23050359165419533', 2147483647),
    (15, '23050359165419535', 353657674),
    (16, '23050359165419536', 436),
    (17, '23050359165419537', 5467),
    (18, '23050359165419538', 565788),
    (19, '23050359165419539', 548759898),
    (20, '23050359165419540', 2443);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `students` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Dumping data for table algo.terms: ~10 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `terms` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `terms` (`term_id`, `term_name_in_nums`, `term_name_in_text`, `term_year`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'term one', 1),
    (2, 2, 'term two', 2),
    (3, 3, 'term three', 3),
    (4, 4, 'term four', 4),
    (5, 5, 'term five', 5),
    (6, 6, 'term six', 6),
    (7, 7, 'term seven', 7),
    (8, 8, 'term eight', 8),
    (9, 9, 'term nine', 9),
    (10, 10, 'term ten', 10);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `terms` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Dumping data for table algo.years: ~15 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `years` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `years` (`year_id`, `year_name_in_nums`, `year_name_in_text`) VALUES
    (1, 2000, '2000/2001'),
    (2, 2001, '2001/2002'),
    (3, 2002, '2002/2003'),
    (4, 2003, '2003/2004'),
    (5, 2004, '2004/2005'),
    (6, 2005, '2005/2006'),
    (7, 2006, '2006/2007'),
    (8, 2007, '2007/2008'),
    (9, 2008, '2008/2009'),
    (10, 2009, '2009/2010'),
    (11, 2010, '2010/2011'),
    (12, 2011, '2011/2012'),
    (13, 2012, '2012/2013'),
    (14, 2013, '2013/2014'),
    (15, 2014, '2014/2015');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `years` ENABLE KEYS */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Comment: what's the error output?

Comment: `/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN
 (select term_year from terms INNER JOIN class_students ON term_year=' at line 2 */`

Comment: What's a year id? Surely a 'year' is its *own* id!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use LEFT JOIN like this... you could use UNION ALL but that would only work if the two queries had the same number of columns and same data type but then you would not be able to distinguish between the two columns as they would be one. Try to eperate them like this this:

```
SELECT
  term_name_in_nums,
  NULL as term_year
FROM
  terms
  INNER JOIN
    class_students ON (term_id=cs_term_id)

UNION ALL

SELECT
  NULL as term_name_in_nums,
  term_year
FROM
  terms
  INNER JOIN
    class_students ON (term_id=cs_term_id)
```

OR try doing this query:

```
SELECT
  terms.term_name_in_nums,
  terms_b.term_year
FROM
  class_students
  INNER JOIN
    terms ON (terms.term_id=class_students.cs_term_id)
  LEFT JOIN
    terms as terms_b ON (terms_b.term_id=class_students.cs_term_id)
```

I do not have table data to test with and what you are trying to get is not that clear. So anyways give it a try and you can probably edit it to work for your situation.

**With above data to help understand what the OP was after:**

```
SELECT
  class_students.cs_id,
  class_students.cs_class_student,
  class_students.cs_class_id,
  class_students.cs_term_id,
  classes.class_name,
  students.student_names,
  students.student_telephone_number,
  terms.term_name_in_nums,
  terms.term_name_in_text,
  terms.term_year,
  years.year_name_in_nums,
  year_name_in_text
FROM
  class_students
  LEFT JOIN classes ON (class_students.cs_class_id=classes.class_id)
  LEFT JOIN students ON (class_students.cs_class_student=students.student_id)
  LEFT JOIN terms ON (class_students.cs_term_id=terms.term_id)
  LEFT JOIN years ON (terms.term_year=years.year_id)
```

This will give all of the class, student, term, and year info for all the records in the class_students table

Output as php array:

```
$class_students = array(
  array('cs_id' => '1','cs_class_student' => '1','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => 'aa','student_telephone_number' => '123456','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '2','cs_class_student' => '1','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => 'aa','student_telephone_number' => '123456','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '3','cs_class_student' => '2','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => 'bb','student_telephone_number' => '5576899','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '4','cs_class_student' => '3','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419520','student_telephone_number' => '788399','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '5','cs_class_student' => '4','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419521','student_telephone_number' => '7892020','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '6','cs_class_student' => '5','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419522','student_telephone_number' => '33772','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '7','cs_class_student' => '6','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419523','student_telephone_number' => '86729','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '8','cs_class_student' => '7','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419524','student_telephone_number' => '526890','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '9','cs_class_student' => '8','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419525','student_telephone_number' => '444332','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '10','cs_class_student' => '9','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419526','student_telephone_number' => '937678','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '11','cs_class_student' => '10','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419527','student_telephone_number' => '44','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '12','cs_class_student' => '11','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419528','student_telephone_number' => '774','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '13','cs_class_student' => '12','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419529','student_telephone_number' => '2147483647','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '14','cs_class_student' => '13','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419531','student_telephone_number' => '2147483647','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '15','cs_class_student' => '14','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419533','student_telephone_number' => '2147483647','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001'),
  array('cs_id' => '16','cs_class_student' => '15','cs_class_id' => '1','cs_term_id' => '1','class_name' => '1','student_names' => '23050359165419535','student_telephone_number' => '353657674','term_name_in_nums' => '1','term_name_in_text' => 'term one','term_year' => '1','year_name_in_nums' => '2000','year_name_in_text' => '2000/2001')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn't well formed in two respects.

The first parenthetical expression makes no sense.

At the end of the query, you seem to be LEFT JOINing this subquery to your top-level query.  But you haven't provided an ON clause for the LEFT JOIN.  You did provide one for the INNER JOIN.

```
        select term_year 
          from terms 
    INNER JOIN class_students ON term_year=cs_term_id
```

If I were you I'd format this query like so, add aliases to all the tables (an alias is required for the subquery), and spell out the ON clauses better.  I've added the last ON clause, but I can't figure out what you're trying to do with it.

```
    select t.term_name_in_nums, t.term_year 
      from terms AS t 
INNER JOIN class_students AS s ON t.term_id=s.cs_term_id
 LEFT JOIN  
   (
        select term_year 
          from terms 
    INNER JOIN class_students ON term_year=cs_term_id
    ) AS y  ON  y.what = what.what
```